# for-loop to compare the two-dimensional array???Help!

Tags: c++

I am currently developing a game in which a player plays slot machine.The game is based on that the user stops in money, 100sek, 300sek or 500sek. Then the user makes a bet for each game. The one-armed bandit randomly spits out 3 different symbols in nine pieces fields. See figure:

[image]
The goal of the game is to obtain as many rows, columns, and diagonals as possible of the same symbol. In the above example that I made, obtained a profit when the upper and lower line have equal symbols, 2 simbles of the same in a row (aaa). 
The following profit system is depending on the number of rows with the same symbol as:

•A series provides 2 * bet

•Two lines giving 3 * bet

•Three rows giving 4 * bet

Four rows gives 5 * bet

•Five lines gives 7 * bet

•Fully playing field gives 10 * bet

I dont know how to solve this problem with the paying? What code can I use? Should I use a for-loop? I'm new with c++ so I'm having trouble with this. I' been spending a lot of hours on this game and I just can't solve it. Please help me! Here's a small part of my code for now: I just want to compare the results. Can somone help me to compare the result after the previous goals I just described. Im thankfull for all the help I get!

```
 srand(time(0)); 
 char game[3][3] = {{'O','X','A'}, {'X','A','X'}, {'A','O','O'}}; 

 for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) 
 { 
 int r = rand() % 3; 
 cout << " " <<game[r][0] << " | " << game[r][1] << " | " << game[r][2] << "\n"; 
 cout << "___|___|___\n"; 
 } 


 //.....compare the two-dimensional array????
```

Comment: If you keep this up, we might need to new stackexchange site for making slot machine games in C++ using two-dimensional arrays (See: http://stackoverflow.com/users/484991/atb)

Comment: What exactly are you hoping to compare? All the above code does is to print something to the console, but that information isn't stored anywhere. Also, what is a series? And how can you get four rows on a board that has only three rows?

Comment: Your code just prints a 3x3 grid of characters. There doesn't seem to be anything to compare to anything? How can you have "Four Rows" when there's only three rows in the grid? I suspect the answer to this is easy once the question makes sense ;)

Comment: Okay sorry for not explaining so well. Im making a slot machine. The player inserts money: 100SEK, 300SEK or 500SEK. And then the player makes a bet which can not exceed the insert amount. The I want the game to begin and three different symbols appear on the screen (X, A and O) in 9 different fields. For example:

Comment: @Steve: LOL, we seem to think quite alike :)

Comment: I tried to explain it much better. Do you understand my problem now?

Comment: @Fred: yup, but you think 6 minutes quicker than me ;)

Comment: @Atb: no, your explanation does not address the questions: what are you trying to compare with what? (There's nothing to compare in your code, and the explanation about matching characters in the slot machine has nothing to with comparing 2-d arrays.) Also, how can you have 'four rows' when there's only 3 rows in the grid. Don't answer in a comment - edit the question.

Comment: I edited the problem again and wrote a pictures

Comment: Would I be right in thinking that 'four rows' means four lines of three identical characters in any direction including diagonal?

Comment: Yes that is correct. Im sorry explaining it so badly. But do you know any code I can use to show the results? Im really bad on c++ and I have to get this done for tomorrow :( I worked with this game for two weeks, and im getting really sick of it :P Do you have any e-mail adress? I can send you the whole code so you can take a look at it? If it's okay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that I understand your requirements perfectly but have decided to interpret them as best I can. This code does what I think you want. I've used 0, 1 and 2 as the characters but you can easily swap them for whatever you want in the output. I've also not bothered calculating the payout since you've written the pseudo-code for that in your question.

```
int game[3][3];
int x, y;
int lines = 0;

// select a random grid
srand(time(0));
for(x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
    for(y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
        game[x][y] = rand() % 3;
        cout << game[x][y];
        if (y == 2)
            cout << '\n';

    }
}

// count horizontal lines
for (y = 0; y < 2; y++)
    if (game[0][y] == game[1][y] && game[0][y] == game[2][y])
        lines++;

// vertical
for (x = 0; x < 2; x++)
    if (game[x][0] == game[x][1] && game[x][0] == game[x][2])
        lines++;

// diagonal
if (game[0][0] == game[1][1] && game[0][0] == game[2][2])
    lines++;
if (game[0][2] == game[1][1] && game[0][2] == game[2][0])
    lines++;

cout << lines << " lines\n";
```

By the way that's my first ever c++ program.

Comment: I think you just made my day!!! God bless you. I just posted a new question but I don't think I needed to. Im gonna try this one now directly!! im so happy :D:D:D I hope it works

Comment: Just one question. How do I get the symbols(a, x, o) insted of numbers?

Comment: @Atb, you need to understand that SO is a community. I've pretty much done all the work for you and yet you have not accepted or even voted my answer. And you *still* want more help.

Comment: Im sorry. Im really thankfull for all the help I got from you. It's just that I'm new on this site and I don't know how it works fully yet and I'm really busy to get my code to work because I'm not very good on c++, the fact is I suck! I have read a book but I'm still not good in making my own functions :/ I'm sorry but you should now that your help has been very usefull for me.

Comment: But do you know how to change the numbers into symbols? You don't have to help me if you don't want to. It's just that I've been working a long time on this game and that's the only thing I got left to solve :/:/   Thank you for all the help you've been very nice to me :)

Comment: Here's a hint: you do not have to change the numbers into symbols in the array - only when you are displaying them. So the only bit you need to change is the cout << bit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [comparison operators](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/operators/) to check if elements in your matrix are equal to each other. You already know how to access each element of your matrix (`game[r][0]`, etc.).

Now, all you have to do is check if elements along a row, diagonal, etc. are equal.

Additionally, you need to **store** your randomly generated symbols. You should create a new matrix (or 2D array) called, say, `results`.

E.g.

```
char results[3][3];
```

Now when you're displaying the slot machine results, store it in this 2D array:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
   int r = rand() % 3;
   cout << " " <<game[r][0] << " | " << game[r][1] << " | " << game[r][2] << "\n"; 
   cout << "___|___|___\n";
   // Store
   for(int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) results[r][j] = game[r][j];
}
```

Above, I've just used another loop to store what you've displayed.

To get you started, here's how to check along a horizontal line for all 3 rows of your matrix:

```
bool horz_equal[3];
for(int r = 0; r < 3; ++r) 
{
  horz_equal[r] = (results[r][0] == results[r][1] && results[r][1] == results[r][2]);
}
```

Additionally, you should think about the method you have for randomly generating symbols. There are better ways!